# Open external file with parameters from Node.js / Electron

Tags: node.js, powerpoint, electron, child-process, fs

I need to open PowerPoint presentations directly as Slideshow in my Electron App, which turned out to be a bit of a challenge.
To start direct in Presentation-Mode PowerPoint demands the Parameter "/s" given with the call to the .exe File.
I tried with the electron shell command and also with nodes child-process (which I would prefer), but I could not figure out how to pass the Parameter.
It would work this way:

```
const cp = require("child_process");
cp.exec('"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\microsoft office\\office14\\powerpnt.exe" /s "C:\\PathToPowerpoint\\file.pptx"')
```

The Problem is,

- I cannot call powerpnt.exe this way, because I have no Idea which Version (and therefore which Path) of PowerPoint is installed on the Client Computer
- It seems there is no way to attach the Parameter somewhere else. `cp.exec('"C:\\PathToPowerpoint\\1.pptx /s"')` (or anything like that) is not accepted by PowerPoint. It Starts, but in "normal" mode.
- I have very few to no possibilities to change or control the files before opening (so no chance of changing every .pptx into a .ppsx)

Does anybody know if there is a way in Node to add PowerPoint to windows system path variables, or determine where "powerpnt.exe" resides on a specific Computer without scanning every Folder, or... any idea?

Comment: Can you call WinAPIs?  If so, you can use FindExecutable to return the path and filename of the executable associated with a specific file type.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but it seems the only predefined node-win32 libraries, are out of date, or only implement a few common things. In fact it would be possible to write a C++ .dll which could be attached to node, but despite the fact that I don't know C++ it seems a bit to much effort for this task.